# SonarLint connected to SonarQube not using "won't fix" or "false positive" from server

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I used SonarQube so far to analyse my project and just tried to also use SonarLint to already get the issues in VS. Now I have the following problem:
I have a few "won't fix" or "false positive" resolved issues on my server and they are not "active" on the server anymore, but they still show up as a warning in VS/SonarLint.

Is this "by design" as the analyzers can't handle that or can I somehow configure this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding resolved issues is not implemented yet in SonarLint for VisualStudio. It's surely going to happen during this year, as this feature was already added in SonarLint for IntelliJ, Eclipse and CLI.

So for the time being this is "by design" (not yet implemented),
but will change soon.

The implementation of this feature is tracked in this ticket (you can vote for it, and subscribe to updates if interested):
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-610

Comment: Thanks for the info. It would be great if you remember and update/comment here as soon as it is implemented.

Comment: Hi @ChrFin I added a link where you can track the progress of the implementation of this feature